# Send API data to Django view

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

**UPDATE:** With karthikr's help (thank you!), I was able to get the server to acknowledge the ajax POST request. As always, fix one problem - run into another.

Here's the relevant code in views.py:

```
def index(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        print('ajax request')
        data = json.loads(request.body, parse_float=Decimal)
```

And here's the AJAX request in index.html:

```
$("#btn1").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.github.com/",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "{% url 'index' %}",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                contentType: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log("success");
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    alert("There was an error posting the data to the server.");
                },
            });
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert("There was an error retrieving the data from the API.");
        },
    });
});
```

If I comment out `data = json.loads(request.body, parse_float=Decimal)`, the Javascript console says success. When I uncomment it, I get "There was an error posting the data to the server" along with a 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR. I'm thinking it probably has to do with the way I'm trying to access the data. I've about a couple different ways to access the JSON that was posted, but none of them seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

The original question is below.

---

Right now I have a working Django application where a user can upload a MongoDB dump and press a button that extracts information from this dump and puts it into various spreadsheets using openpyxl.

This is what the method in views.py looks like to take the uploaded JSON and put it into spreadsheets.

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            uploadedfile = request.FILES['docfile']
            data = json.load(uploadedfile)
            num_lines = sum(len(v) for v in data.itervalues())
            generate_report(data, num_lines)

            zip_subdir = 'locationsreport'
            zip_filename = '%s.zip' % zip_subdir

            s = StringIO.StringIO()
            zf = z.ZipFile(s, 'w')
            zf.write('Bing.xlsx')
            zf.write('Facebook.xlsx')
            zf.write('Foursquare.xlsx')
            zf.write('Google.xlsx')
            zf.close()

            response = HttpResponse(s.getvalue(), content_type='application/x-zip-compressed')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % zip_filename
            return response
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()

    return render_to_response(
        'report/index.html',
        {'form': form,},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

`generate_report(data, num_lines)` makes a call to a method in a separate file (tasks.py) that just walks through the JSON and puts things into cells in the spreadsheet.

I'm trying to update it so that rather than upload a database dump, the user can simply press a button which makes an AJAX call (at my manager's request) to an external API and parses the data to put it into spreadsheets like before. However, I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how this would work.

Here's my AJAX call (in index.html):

```
$(function() {
    $("#btn1").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://api.github.com/",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "{% url 'index' %}",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: data,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log("success");
                    },
                    error: function(data) {
                        alert("There was an error posting the data to the server.");
                    },
                });
                // alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert("There was an error retrieving the data from the API.");
            },
        });
    });
});
```

I'm just using that GET request URL for testing purposes. The GET works properly - originally, the success statement was just the commented out line (alert(JSON.stringify(data)) and it would spit out the data from the URL. However, when I try to make a POST to the index, I get the alert saying "There was an error posting the data to the server." How can I go about successfully making a post to the server so that my function in views.py can take this information and put it into a spreadsheet?

Also, would I maybe be better off ditching this AJAX request in favor of some other method of getting the information from the API?

Sorry if this is unclear - it's kinda hard to describe exactly what I'm trying to do. I'll try to answer any questions about it if anyone has suggestions.

Comment: You should do a `console.log(data)` in the error callback to see what the error response is..

Comment: It says "POST http ://x.x.x.x:8000/report/ 403 (FORBIDDEN)" and then "Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "↵<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html lang="en">↵<head>↵  <meta h…AILURE_VIEW setting.</p>↵</div>↵↵</body>↵</html>↵", status: 403, statusText: "FORBIDDEN"}" - I'm not really sure how to interpret that.

Comment: I was doing some reading, and it looks like one thing that may cause a 403 is the lack of a `{% csrf_token %}` in the form with the POST - however, in the case of my button, it's not part of a form. Would it perhaps be good to put this button in a form? **EDIT** Just tried putting the button in a form and it broke the ajax GET request.

Comment: Your `data` does not seem to have the management information it needs (the ones csrf generates) - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax

Comment: That seems to have fixed part of the problem. Thanks! I updated the original question with my latest issue.

Comment: Are you familiar with pdb ? You can just do `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()`, and then execute the error line in the console to see what is going on.

Comment: I didn't even know that existed (very little experience with Python) - but it helped me solve my problem. Thanks so much for all of your help!

Comment: Glad it helped.. Do remember to remove pdb statements before you push code  :)